# Plot a line graph Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to create the following chart in Mathematica.

[image]

I would like to somehow generate this based on Ohm's law not just a raw data set.

I would like to be able to switch the resistance value to update the chart and increase the voltage in 5-V steps from 0 to 30 V

Any help would be greatly appreciated I'm totally stuck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have a look at `Manipulate` to learn how you can enter the resistance value and update the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You will find that the line slope looks the same while the y axis scale changes as the value of r is varied. There are simple plot options you can use to change that effect.

```
i[v_, r_] := v/r;
Manipulate[
   Plot[i[v, r], {v, 1, 5000}, PlotRange -> All], {r, 100, 50000}]
```